# How to interpret the .pfm disparity maps of Middlebury 2014 dataset as integer values?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I try to work with the [Middlebury 2014 stereo dataset](https://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/submit3/). The dataset contains ground truth disparity maps contained in a .pfm file.

From what I read online, I can load the .pfm file into a cv::Mat like so:

```
cv::Mat = cv::imread(path, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

This seems to correctly load the floating point values from the pfm. However, the per-pixel values don't make sense to me. They are much larger than the actual disparity values between left and right view.

So how do I convert those values to integral disparity values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale the disparity by the given factor in the *.pfm file. Described in [PFM format](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/NETPBM/doc/pfm.html), the third line of the *.pfm file gives the scale factor.

Multiply the disparity map you got with the scale factor, and you can get the real disparity map. The range is from [200, 800], the same as described in the original paper.

You can also see this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/singer-yang/Middlebury-Depth-Map) for the processing code.